# Is this a helpful way to think about Coltrane Substitution?

Tags: theory, jazz

More specifically, is it harmful?  From the ii-V-I I could backtrack from the I and suss out the flatVImaj7 and the IIImaj7, but what about:

Bar 1 ii-up a half step to a dominant -

Bar2 down a fourth to a maj7 - up a minor third to a dominant -

Bar 3 down a fourth to a maj7 - up a minor third to a dominant -   <-- this is the original V

Bar 4 I

Answer (score 1):

That's a rule of thumb for copying them. If you want to THINK about them, understand two things.

That you can jump to just about ANY chord and start a ii, V, I pattern.  And if you jump to one (say) a major third away, then, having completed that sequence jump another major third, you're building a pattern, and patterns are very powerful things in music!  When you do something 'wrong' three times over, it starts sounding 'right'!

And the idea of b5 (or 'tritone') substitutions for a chord that has a dominant function.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  I'm just focusing on this one pattern this month.  Don't see a "them" here.   I started looking at "Countdown" (played at amateur guitar player speed) and have been drilling this substitution in all 12 keys and all the positions I can find.

Comment: @GlueWrangler -- "Don't see a 'them' here." Multiple chord substitutions, and the fact that these seem to be called "Coltrane changes" more often than "Coltrane substitution" (though I have also seen "Coltrane substitutions") suggests that "them" is appropriate.

Comment: I'm talking about one particular pattern which I spelled out so there's no "them".  ii-V-I is also not a "them".  Do you think this is a helpful way of thinking about it or harmful, as opposed to reverse engineering the flatVI and the III?